# How to access this inside prototype function in js

Tags: node.js, prototype

I am using nodejs and mysql client in nodejs
I am trying to use pool function od the mysql module.

```
"use strict";
var mysqlClient = require('mysql')
  , dbPool = mysqlClient.createPool(require('../config/database'));
function MyModel(params) {
  this.tbl = params.tbl;
  this.primary_key = params.primary_key;
  this.primary_name = params.primary_name;
  this.dbPool = dbPool;
}
module.exports = MyModel;
//primary key
MyModel.prototype.fromPK = function fromPK(pk, callback) {
  this.dbPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM " + this.tbl + " WHERE " + this.primary_key + " = " + connection.escape(pk);
    connection.query(query, callback);
  });
};
```

I know I cannot access `this` inside getConnection and I could simply set `var t = this` outside it and access it with var t, but is there any other way to access `this` var in this condition. Should I define `var t = this` in each prototype function I write?

I have following detailed gist
https://gist.github.com/yalamber/6bd1df0cc27849eb09b3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine what `this` is in a function using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

The elaborate syntax is:

```
var newfunction = oldfunction.bind(THIS_OBJECT);
```

That would make `THIS_OBJECT` be the `this` object inside the `oldfunction`. As you can see, `.bind()` returns a new (bound) function.

You don't need that elaborate syntax though, it works on anonymous functions as well:

```
var newfunction = function() { ... }.bind(THIS_OBJECT);
```

In your case, you could use this:

```
this.dbPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM " + this.tbl + " WHERE " + this.primary_name + " = " + connection.escape(pn);
  connection.query(query, callback);
}.bind(this));
```

This makes the `this` inside the callback function the same as the `this` on the outside.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. I should keep learning js there are many things to learn here :)